# Django: Listing documents from a local folder

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I've been trying to find a way to display my documents from a local folder on to a web page. I was wondering about this in two ways: one was to use django's ListView, but I am not using models in this case, so I am unsure if it would work. The other way I'm going with this is by through this list method that I've made, but I am having trouble getting the proper contents (title, date) on to the webpage. They show up in lists that I created, but wont translate to the webpage. Its just a blank page. Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
import os, string, markdown, datetime
from P1config.settings import STATICBLOG_COMPILE_DIRECTORY,STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY,STATICBLOG_STORAGE

def doclist(request):

    mdown =  markdown.Markdown(extensions = ['meta','extra', 'codehilite', PyEmbedMarkdown()])
    posts = []

    for item in os.listdir(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY):
        if item.endswith('.md'):
            continue
        try:           
            with open(os.path.join(STATICBLOG_POST_DIRECTORY, item)) as fhandle:
                content = fhandle.read() # (opening and reading the ENTIRE '.md' document)
                mdown.convert(content)   # (converting file from '.md' to ".html")

                post = { 'file_name' : item }

                if 'title' in mdown.Meta and len(mdown.Meta['title'][0]) > 0:
                    post['title'] = mdown.Meta['title'][0]
                else:
                    post['title'] = string.capwords(item.replace('-', ' '))
                if 'date' in mdown.Meta:
                    post['date'] = mdown.Meta['date'][0]
                    post['date']= datetime.datetime.strptime(post['date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
                posts.append(post) 
        except:
            pass

    from operator import itemgetter
    posts = sorted(posts, key=itemgetter('date')) 
    posts.reverse()

    return render(  
        request,
        'list.html',
        {'post' : posts}
    )
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if post %}
        {% for i in post %}
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <p class="meta">{{post.date}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{%  endblock %}
```

and my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('blog_static.views',
    (r'^postlist/', 'list'), 
)
```

I have two questions:

1. Can you figure out where I am going wrong in this code?
2. Are there any alternative ways that I may go about doing this? This may be an inefficient way of listing documents from a local folder, so I am open to other options as well.

Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are already familiar with, and could execute this using `ListView`. You can use `ListView` without a model - as referenced in various parts of the documentation ("is not necessarily a queryset"):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset

> Get the list of items for this view. This must be an iterable and may be a queryset (in which queryset-specific behavior will be enabled).

Therefore you should be able to do the following:

```
class MyListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'foobar.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

What's wrong with your example... it's the fact you're referencing `post` in your inner for loop as opposed to the `i` that you defined as the actual post.

It's confusing because you rename the python `posts` variable to `post` in the template context, then iterate over it as `i`.

`posts` in your template context is just a list, and has no attributes, keys, etc., named `post.title`.

Comment: My goodness...I cant believe I overlooked that; but thats why I like this community: the extra set of eyes. Thanks a ton. I managed to fix up my view and get the list up and going.

...and as for the ListView, I am a bit familiar with it, but only in implementation with models. I hardly see it used for other means, and I was not entirely sure that I can use it use it outside of the models, but your info sure has me curious. I'm going to see what I can make happen with them. Django docs, imo, is not entirely useful b/c it seems they expect you to know a certain amount of info before you read.

Comment: @JellisHeRo I find the django documentation as one of the holy grails of documentation quality. I specifically enjoy how well they point out the stuff other docs assume you know. That said the CBV docs need some knowledge to proceed. Each CBV is composed of other generic mixins that are listed - and reading into how those work is the key to understanding CBVs.

Answer (score 1):

`post` is array of dict objects. So

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if post %}
        {% for i in post %}
        <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
        <p class="meta">{{i.date}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{%  endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I totally missed on that, so thanks for catching the mistake!! Turns out that was my big roadblock.